# Angular2 apply filter inside service

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I am building an app with `Angular 2`. I have a **service**, and I am trying to **filter the data** before getting it from the service. I want a function where I can just **ask one project element instead of the whole array**.

This is the code I tried, but this approach doesn't work:

```
getProject(id: number): Observable<Project> {
        return this.http.get(this.url).map(this.extractData).filter(project => (<Project>project).id == id).catch(this.handleError2);

    // return this.getProjects().filter(project => project.id === id);
    //return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then(x => x.json().data.filter(project => project.id === id)[0]).catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
}

private handleError2 (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
    error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to filter data in component from where you have called the service.

So your service is like :

```
getProject(id: number): Observable<Project> {
  return this.http.get(this.url).map(this.extractData);
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body.data || []; // return value must be array to use filter function in component
}
```

in your component you can do as below :

```
service.getProject(projectId).subscribe((res) => {
  let filtered = [];
  if(res.length){
    filtered = res.filter((item) => {
      return item.id === projectId;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you're mixing sync and async code, and return doesn't work like that. You can return an object (function) who's properties change later (aka a Promise)

I doubt that `http.get()` provides an array for you to map

---

`.toPromise()` seems like a hack, but you should return a Promise chain

---

```
return this.http.get(this.url).then(data => data.map(this.extractData).filter(project => (<Project>project).id == id).catch(this.handleError2));
```

If `this.http.get()` does not return a Promise, but takes a callback, you can construct one:

```
return new Promise (resolve => this.http.get(this.url, resolve)).then(data => data.map(this.extractData).filter(project => (<Project>project).id == id).catch(this.handleError2));
```

And whatever is calling `getProject()` can chain with `getProject().then()`

Comment: Yea your right there actually nod good solution. The problem is that I use a json file and not a service so I cannot make a getProject() function that gives the variable through to the backend. So I think the best approach is to put it inside the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

If this part of code works :

```
getProjects() {
        return this.http.get(this.url).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError2);
     }
```

Then you can call a single project with :

```
getProject(id: number) {
        return this.getProjects()
            .then(projects => projects.filter(project => (<Project>project).id == id);
    }
```